# Datatable paging number exceeds to expected number

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Jquery Datatables and experiencing some problems in deferred loading using ajax.

One of my problems is that the page number exceeds to the expected page.
For example:

I got `1 to 10 of 82`, I'm expecting that the page number goes from `1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 8` only but I'm experiencing this instead `1, ..., 9, 10, 11` and they are active buttons and display no data at all.

Here is an example of my settings to datatables

```
$('#table').DataTable({
        processing: true, 
        serverSide: true, 
        deferLoading: totalData,   
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: { data },
        autoWidth: false,
        responsive: true,
        ordering: false,
        scrollX: true,
        dom: "Bfrtip",
 });
```

[image: And the sample of the page here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As default page length is 10

Incorrect data within paging number is maybe from your server side processing.

You can inspect the network JSON response from your server and make sure its follow Datatable request params especially `start` and `length` when querying from database.

Example of Datatable Ajax request params:

```
draw: 1
columns[0][data]: id
columns[0][name]: 
columns[0][searchable]: true
columns[0][orderable]: true
columns[0][search][value]: 
columns[0][search][regex]: false
columns[1][data]: file_name
columns[1][name]: 
columns[1][searchable]: true
columns[1][orderable]: true
columns[1][search][value]: 
columns[1][search][regex]: false
columns[2][data]: delivery_qty
columns[2][name]: 
columns[2][searchable]: true
columns[2][orderable]: true
columns[2][search][value]: 
columns[2][search][regex]: false
columns[3][data]: submission_status
columns[3][name]: 
columns[3][searchable]: true
columns[3][orderable]: true
columns[3][search][value]: 
columns[3][search][regex]: false
order[0][column]: 0
order[0][dir]: asc
start: 0
length: 10
search[value]: 
search[regex]: false
action: get_submission_data
_: 1563616425364
```

Example of response JSON format:

`{"draw":1,"recordsFiltered":0,"recordsTotal":0,"data":[{1,..},{2,..}]}`

Answer (score 0):

add `pageLength: 10,` to **DataTable** and try again:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
        processing: true, 
        serverSide: true, 
        deferLoading: totalData,  
        pageLength: 10, 
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: { data },
        autoWidth: false,
        responsive: true,
        ordering: false,
        scrollX: true,
        dom: "Bfrtip",
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If number of pages is incorrect initially, then the value of `totalData` is invalid or incorrect.

When you use [`deferLoading`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading) option, value of `totalData` will determine number of pages displayed.